# What happened to sdk platform android 2.3 api 9 revision 1?

Tags: android

I'm using WROX Android Application Development which recommends using platform android 2.3 api 9 revision 1?

I noticed that it's not showing in the Android SDK Manager.  My smartphone uses Gingerbread and what to dev for it.

What are my options?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

API level 9 is obsolete and replaced by API level 10 (which is still 2.3. aka gingerbread).

You can show it in the SDK manager by clicking the "obsolete" checkbox at the bottom, but you should use API level 10 instead.